# LiftingWaveletTransform with irregular grids

Tags: wavelet-analysis

One of the properties mentioned in the literature about the lifting wavelet transform is that it can be applied on irregular meshes or grids (i.e. not equally spaced samples); but I don't seem to see that as an option in `LiftingWaveletTransform`. Any ideas on how to do that using *Mathematica*'s wavelet analysis tools?

Answer (score 1):

Construct an "irregular grid" with a vertical discontinuity:

```
a = {{ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], ConstantArray[1, {3, 5}]}, {ConstantArray[0, {5, 3}], 
   ConstantArray[1, {5, 5}]}}
```

Use ArrayFlatten to  get a rectangular matrix:

```
b = ArrayFlatten@a

WaveletMatrixPlot[LiftingWaveletTransform[b]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eldo, but b is just a `{8,8}` array and, therefore, representing a signal/function in a regular grid of $(i/8,j/8)$ points, that is not irregular.